# catch error in php and return it as json to html

Tags: php, html, json

is it possible to catch error in a php file, lets say in the connection section, and return it to the HTML file as json for printing.

This is my try:

```
<?php
    $srevernme = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "db";

    //create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($srevernme,$username,$password,$dbname);

    $errors = array();  // array to hold connection errors

    //check connection                                              //<-----POSSIBLE ERROR
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         $data['success'] = false;
         $errors['error_info'] = "connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error ."Please try later.";
         $data['errors'] = $errors;
         echo json_encode($data);
        //die("connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
    }



if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
    {        
        if (isset($_POST["fnameInput"]) && isset($_POST["lnameInput"]) && isset($_POST["addressInput"]) && isset($_POST["cityInput"]) && isset($_POST["zipcodeInput"]))
        {
            // prepare and bind
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name) VALUES (?, ?)");

            if ($stmt == FALSE) {                                       //<-----POSSIBLE ERROR          
                $data['success'] = false;
                $errors['error_info'] = "Connection failed: Cannot create connection to sql DB. Please try later.";
                $data['errors'] = $errors;
                echo json_encode($data);
                //die("Connection failed: Cannot create connection to sql DB. Please try later.");
                }

           if (empty($errors)) 
           { 
                    //mark as success
                    $data = array(); //array for saving the data
                    $data['success'] = true;

                    //get wanted data....

                   $data['wanted_data'] = json_encode($some_data);
                   echo json_encode($data);

                   $stmt->close();
            }
    }
    $conn->close();
```

The relevant sections are marked with `//<-----POSSIBLE ERROR`.
To be clear- `data` represents the data I want to `echo` to the html file and it had a key named `success` that his values are `true` if everything is ok or `false` if there is an error.

EDIT:
In the current state the php file send request in this format when I shot down MySQL server (from chrome inspector):

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli::mysqli():  in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\register.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\ex3\register.php</b> on line <b>26</b><br />
{"success":false,"error_info":"Connection failed: Cannot create connection to sql DB. Please try later."}<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function bind_param() on null in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\ex3\register.php</b> on line <b>39</b><br />
```

Thanks!

Comment: `and return it to the HTML file as json for printing.` Which HTML file??

Comment: `if (empty($errors)) ` ??? `$errors` is never used??

Comment: @JensonMJohn, probably an ajax call. I don't think we need to worry about that.

So, what exactly is the problem here, user9? At a quick glance, it seems to me like you've got the right idea and it should work (even though I would've done it a bit differently myself). You should probably add an 'error' section to the json array at all times, so you can actually check with your ajax call whether or not an error ocurred, before you start using whatever you've returned (as to not get any undefined errors and such) -- also, shouldn't `empty($errors)` be `$stmt`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly My bad.. I fixed the code. thanks.

Comment: @JensonMJohn The html file that made the ajax call to this php file

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have database named `db` in `MySQL` server. I don't think that it is relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, is *that* what you mean?

It seems the `JSON` arrives just fine. What you mean is to *disable* php errors? In this case, you can turn off `php`'s standard error reporting, so it only shows your custom errors. (Note that this means you will not get an error that you aren't manually taking care of)

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php for more information.

```
// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);
```

This will prevent `php` from echo-ing its own errors, thus only returning your (valid) json_encoded errors.

**edit:**
You'll want to return `json_encode($errors)` instead of `json_encode($data)` in case of an error.

**edit#2:**
I would really advise you to not return anything until you've reached the end of your script, so it's less confusing. Simply put an `if` statement at the end.

```
if(!empty($errors)){
 echo json_encode($errors);
 return false; //don't go on
}
else{
 echo json_encode($data);
 return false; //don't go on
}
```

In case of an error, simply add to the `$errors` array, as it seems to me that's what you're wanting to do in the first place.

Comment: Not a good idea really, **specially** as OP is getting a connection error and therefore not connecting to the database server

Comment: @RiggsFolly What does that matter? The question here isn't the fact that he's getting an error. The question here is how to format error reporting in a specific way, which is exactly what he is already doing. If he wants a valid JSON response, he has to manually make that happen. The PHP standard errors cause invalid json to return.

Comment: **yup** But it would be better to _FIX The Errors_ rather than ignore them_

Comment: Well, I just figured he had created the error on purpose for debugging purposes. I'm not sure how you'd format errors without getting any, but I'd rather create them. Sidenote: He does *not* ignore them, nor do I. He catches the error manually. That will not be affected by `error_reporting`.